# Modifying an instance of a class when it is created

Tags: python-3.x, oop, init

I have this code:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom
        self = self.to_lowest_form()

    def to_lowest_form(self):
        from math import gcd

        d = 0
        while d != 1:
            d = gcd(self.num, self.den)
            self.num //= d
            self.den //= d

        return Fraction(self.num, self.den)

    def __add__(self, other):
        pass
```

As above code shows, I need to get a **fraction** then put it to its lowest form after it is initialized.
(I get a **RecursionError** and I know why).

So my question is how can i convert a newly created **fraction** to its lowest term (so as to avoid calling **instance.lowest_form()** in every method) ?

Comment: Never assign to `self`. That is the actual instance object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just making things more complicated by returning a new instance of `Fraction` when reducing the numerator/denominator in the `to_lowest_form` method, instead of returning the reduced numbers themselves. Consider keeping the reduced numbers as attributes instead, *after* calculating their reduced form internally.

Implementation example:

```
from math import gcd

class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.num, self.den = self.reduce(num=top, den=bottom)

    @staticmethod
    def reduce(num, den):
        d = 0
        while d != 1:
            d = gcd(num, den)
            num //= d
            den //= d
        return num, den
```

Comment: Thanks @jfaccioni .  That did it.  PS : You should  indent the "return" in the "reduce" method.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Fixed the typo.